# listFiles() of File not working on symbolic links?

Tags: java, file-io, symlink

I have the following File object pointing to a directory via symbolic link,

```
File directory = new File("/path/symlink/foo/bar");
String[] files = directory.listFiles();
```

listFiles() returns null, is this because of the symlink? if yes, how will I go about this if I really want to list the files in bar using the path that contains a symlink?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to what I've seen while Googling this puzzling behavior, Java requires that you call `.getCanonicalFile()` on a `File` whose path contains a link before you can use it in other file operations.

So:

```
File directory = new File("/path/symlink/foo/bar").getCanonicalFile();
String[] files = directory.listFiles();
```

Answer (score 3):

You could read the Symbolic [LINK](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/io/links.html)

Answer (score 2):

..extending what @mickthompson suggested, using the [NIO File library](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/package-summary.html) (> Java 7) you can:

```
Path link = Paths.get("/path/symlink/foo/bar");
while (Files.isSymbolicLink(link)) {
    link = Files.readSymbolicLink(link);
}

Path[] files =  Files.list(link).toArray(size -> new Path[size]);
```

---

[`Path`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) is easily converted to [`File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) so all your old Java IO code can be safely kept, *@see* [`Path#toFile()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#toFile()).

Comment: Note, that the could be chain of symbolic links. So if would be safer to replace `if` with `while`.

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed for the 3.0.1 release. After that's released, give it a try and let us know if it's still a problem for you by opening a new bug, linking back to [this one](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68262460) for context.